# Python doctest how to match single or double quote in output as opposed to only single quote

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

I commonly use the [code auto-formatter `Black`](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which has trained me to use double quotes.
It has become "muscle memory" for me to use double quotes.

The default `repr` for many classes prints from the Python interactive output with single quotes.  I know doctest seeks to reproduce the Python interactive output.

Is there some simple way to have doctest match single or double quotes?

I know one option is to make a custom [`doctest.OutputChecker`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#outputchecker-objects).  I am wondering if there's a simpler option.

---

**Code Sample**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    """Contains a string."""

    data: str


def get_some_dataclass(data: str) -> SomeDataClass:
    """Get a data class containing some specified data.

    Returns:
        Data class containing the data.

    Examples:
        >>> get_some_dataclass("hi")
        SomeDataClass(data="hi")

    """
    return SomeDataClass(data=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()
```

Output:

```
**********************************************************************
File "quote_or_apostrophe.py", line 23, in __main__.get_some_dataclass
Failed example:
    get_some_dataclass("hi")
Expected:
    SomeDataClass(data="hi")
Got:
    SomeDataClass(data='hi')
**********************************************************************
```

---

**Versions**

I invoke doctest via pytest's [doctest integration](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/doctest.html).

```
python==3.8.2
pytest==5.4.1
```

Comment: Given that the test input is hard-coded, the simplest thing to do would be to simply use single quotes in the expected output. Python doesn't switch between the two arbitrarily; `str.__repr__` only uses double quotes if the string itself contains a double quote. That's not the case here, so you can rely on the output using single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could achieve this with [blacken-docs](https://github.com/asottile/blacken-docs) but I haven't seen an example of this done yet...

Either the approach of:

- Leave the strings in black standard (double quoted) and find a way to transform the expected output doctest so that it has double quotes (by running black on it somehow?)
- Run `blacken-docs` with a single quote setting applied, which also avoids having to think about it yourself

I would instinctively go for the first option because it feels like it solves the problem better, but I expect it is easier to do the latter (and TBH not needing to think about this too much would be a plus).

Upon looking into it though, this doesn't seem supported at present [according to this issue](https://github.com/asottile/blacken-docs/issues/46), and running `blacken-docs` on some code which prints a double-quoted `__repr__` in a `>>>` doctest block does not affect said double quoting.

My interpretation of that issue and the other one it links to is that `blacken-docs` does not support code blocks in the format:

```
"""
Docstring starts here.

Code example comes next:

  >>> from some_module import some_func
  >>> some_func(1, 2)
  "1+2"

"""
```

I've tried rewriting code in the suggested format:

```
"""
Docstring starts here.

Code example comes next:

.. code-block:: python

    >>> from some_module import some_func
    >>> some_func(1, 2)
    "1+2"

"""
```

but this gives me

```
code block parse error Cannot parse: 1:0: >>> from some_module import some_func
```

So I'm not going to use blacken-docs or the more verbose `.. code-block: python` format, perhaps in time it'll be supported.